# Flexbox behaving different in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a pretty simple flexbox gallery editor. I got it working in chrome pretty fast, but with Firefox I am experiencing trouble.

This is how it looks in chrome

[image: Normal display]
[image: Hover]

And this is how it looks in Firefox

[image: Normal display]
[image: Hover]

What I could find out by inspecting is, that the space on the right in Firefox equals the width of the add button. I checked some styling but just couldn't find the issue with my css.

Here is my scss and a link to a Pastebin with the CSS: https://pastebin.com/FbAPzM8P

```
.gallery-images {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    &.horizontal-scroll {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        padding-top: 7.5%;
        padding-left: 2em;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        .gallery-image {
            height: 80%;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex: 0 0 0;
            .gallery-image-content {
                display: flex;
                flex: 0 0 100%;
                height: 100%;
                .gallery-image-action {
                    width: 8em;
                }
                .gallery-image-content {
                    height: 100%;
                }
                .gallery-image-image, .gallery-image-action {
                    display: flex;
                    height: 100%;
                    > img {
                        height: 100%;
                    }
                }
            }
            .gallery-image-action-bar {
                flex: 0 0 100%;
                padding-right: 10px;
                padding-left: 10px;
                margin-top: -18px;
                .button-bar {
                    margin-left: 7.5em;
                    text-align: left;
                    padding-right: 2px;
                    .button-action-left {
                        float: left;
                    }
                    .button-action-right {
                        float: right;
                        margin-right: -2px;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /** different way of displaying the editor **/
    .gallery-image {
        .gallery-image-content {
            .gallery-image-image, .gallery-image-action {
                position: relative;
                border: 10px solid transparent;
                .gallery-image-edit, .gallery-image-add, .gallery-image-edit-button {
                    cursor: pointer;
                    transition: transform 0.3s, background 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
                    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
                    &:hover {
                        background: darken($gray-100, 6%);
                        transform: scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 1);
                    }
                }
                .gallery-image-edit-button {
                    background: $gray-100;
                    position: absolute;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    opacity: 0;
                    z-index: 10;
                    &:hover {
                        opacity: 0.8;
                        border-radius: 4px;
                        + .gallery-image-edit {
                            background: darken($gray-100, 6%);
                            transform: scale3d(0.95, 0.95, 1);
                            border-radius: 4px;
                        }
                    }
                    &::before, &::after {
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 0;
                        margin-top: -0.35em;
                        width: 100%;
                        color: $primary;
                        font-size: 1.5em;
                        font-family: FontAwesome;
                        pointer-events: none;
                    }
                    &::before {
                        content: '\f040';
                    }
                    &::after {
                        margin-top: -0.5em;
                        color: $primary;
                        content: '\f040';
                        font-size: 3em;
                        opacity: 0;
                        transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
                        transform: scale3d(2, 2, 1);
                    }
                }
                .gallery-image-edit {
                    opacity: 1;
                    z-index: 8;
                }
                > div {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    &.gallery-image-add {
                        border-radius: 4px;
                        background: darken($gray-100, 2%);
                        &::before, &::after {
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 50%;
                            left: 0;
                            margin-top: -0.35em;
                            width: 100%;
                            color: $primary;
                            font-size: 1.5em;
                            font-family: FontAwesome;
                            pointer-events: none;
                        }
                        &::before {
                            content: '\f067';
                        }
                        &::after {
                            margin-top: -0.5em;
                            color: $primary;
                            content: '\f00c';
                            font-size: 3em;
                            opacity: 0;
                            transition: opacity 0.3s, transform 0.3s;
                            transform: scale3d(2, 2, 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .gallery-image-action-bar {
            .button-bar {
                .button-action-left {
                    @extend .button;
                    @extend .button.primary;
                }
                .button-action-right {
                    @extend .button;
                    @extend .button.primary;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the SCSS highlighted: https://github.com/Jinya-CMS/Jinya-Gallery-CMS/blob/0af7c5dc7644d35f09de9edb3fbc98a863ececb7/src/DesignerBundle/Resources/public/scss/_gallery-designer.scss

And this the rendered HTML, here is a Pastebin to the HTML rendered by Firefox: https://pastebin.com/pjRvdEYJ

```
<div class="gallery-images horizontal-scroll" data-source="http://localhost:8000/designer/gallery/artworks/images" data-move="http://localhost:8000/designer/gallery/artworks/%23tempid%23">
    <!-- ko foreach: images -->

    <div class="gallery-image">
        <div class="gallery-image-content">
            <div class="gallery-image-action">
                <div class="gallery-image-add" role="button" data-bind="click: $root.addImage"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-image-image">
            <div class="gallery-image-edit-button" role="button" data-bind="click: $root.editImage"></div><img data-bind="attr: { src: source }" class="gallery-image-edit" src="https://placebear.com/1920/1080" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery-image-action-bar">
            <div class="button-bar">
                <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko if: $index() !== ($parent.images().length - 1) -->
                 <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-image">
        <div class="gallery-image-content">
            <div class="gallery-image-action">
                <div class="gallery-image-add" role="button" data-bind="click: $root.addImage"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-image-image">
            <div class="gallery-image-edit-button" role="button" data-bind="click: $root.editImage"></div><img data-bind="attr: { src: source }" class="gallery-image-edit" src="http://localhost:8000//public/content_image/d80dfe5ad6693c43a31019ee9398554fd7cc4470fcec159a427e886ab9634982" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery-image-action-bar">
            <div class="button-bar">
                <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
                 <!-- /ko -->
                 <!-- ko if: $index() !== ($parent.images().length - 1) -->
                 <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-image">
        <div class="gallery-image-content">
            <div class="gallery-image-action">
                <div class="gallery-image-add" role="button" data-bind="click: $root.addImage"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="gallery-image-image">
            <div class="gallery-image-edit-button" role="button" data-bind="click: $root.editImage"></div><img data-bind="attr: { src: source }" class="gallery-image-edit" src="http://localhost:8000//public/content_image/4c58d75659edeb84f342376679c9f5382db0181920f9206fcc7e86648a8246c9" /></div>
        </div>

        <div class="gallery-image-action-bar">
            <div class="button-bar">
                <!-- ko if: $index() !== 0 -->
                 <!-- /ko -->
                 <!-- ko if: $index() !== ($parent.images().length - 1) --><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- /ko -->

    <div class="gallery-image">
        <div class="gallery-image-content">
            <div class="gallery-image-action">
                <div class="gallery-image-add" role="button" data-bind="click: addImage"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have an idea for me where I can check for the issue or even has a solution?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the issue with the posted code, so if you want a proper answer, add a working code snippet so we can see what the images show.

Comment: @LGSon I added pastebin links with the full rendered HTML and CSS.

Comment: One big issue here is the `height: 100%;` you used all over. With Flexbox that is not gonna do well (will more likely break it than make it). Flex items has either `align-items: stretch` (default) for flex _row_ items, or `flex-grow: 1`/`flex: 1` for flex _column_ items, that one should use to make them fill the height. So start with rework your code with that and see where it goes.

Comment: @LGSon, interesting that it works in Chrome without any issue. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Yes, Chrome make a guess what you are trying to do, and by that violate the Flexbox rules to make it look good. Whether that is good or bad depends who you ask...and IMHO it is bad, since it won't work cross browsers.

Comment: The other reason is, that the specs. is sometimes not detailed enough, or allow different interpretations of the behavior, and when, you won't find 2 browser manufacturer making their browser render the same, so sometimes one is better than the other, and the other way around. And who is correct? ... Both, as the definitions (or lack of) allows them to be.

Comment: @LGSon, ok, I tried around with it and I just can&#39;t get it work. Could you provide a jsfiddle with more information on how to adjust the scss? I actually know how to achieve what I want without flexbox, but the code would be horribly long, so a flexbox solution would be great

Comment: If you can break it down to a minimal code snippet, that reproduce the issue, I'll have a look, because as it is now, it is to much work and I don't have the extra time.

Comment: @LGSon After looking around I decided to try a simple inline-block approach and it worked again only worked in Chrome and not in Firefox. So I suppose there must be generell problem with the CSS in general, so I will throw it away and build it from ground new.

Comment: When you do, do not use `height: 100%` on flex items, use Flexbox's own properties I mentioned in a previous comment.